# Server-to-server communications using cURL, HTTPS POST

Tags: php, curl, https, security

I'm implementing server to server communications that should (probably) look like this:

**client** (*web browser*) <--> (*web app*) **server** (*service client*) <--> (*service app*) **central server**

Some of the client requests are processed locally and some are performed as remote service calls (not RPC). Request to central server is formatted as HTTPS POST and then sent using cURL; server replies with appropriate JSON message.

Problem is, I'm using HTTPS and it takes some additional time for certificate verification, each time service query is performed. It's possible to re-use cURL handle and send 'keep-alive' connection header, but..  In current MVC implementation, each new client request results in new instance of web app (and corresponding service client) - meaning, handle is re-initialized and https connection is established anew.

So, the following questions arise:

1. Is there some way to speed-up such HTTPS requests? E.g., somehow bypass verification after first successful connection?
2. May I forgo HTTPS (specifically, its time-consuming certificate check procedure) and encrypt/decrypt POST and JSON on my own (for example, using mcrypt) in conjunction with some authorization method (Diffie-Hellman)?
3. Am I doing something completely wrong and should immediately stop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you measured the overhead of the HTTPS connection ? Is it really significant ?

If you would like to avoid doing the handshake for each request, you could try setting up a persistent secured connection between the server and the central server.

You could do that with a SSH tunnel, a VPN, etc.

**Edit**: A local reverse HTTP proxy that maintains a keep-alive connection on the central server would be an option too.

Comment: Yes, overhead is like 3 to 5 times larger, compared with http.

Comment: Also, if I use SSH tunnel, it will be similar to sockets implementation. As I understand, that contradicts current idea of using cURL (and RESTful-like protocol).

Comment: The tunnel may be a virtual network between two servers, not necessarily a direct connection to the service. Also take a look at the local reverse proxy solution.

Answer (score 0):

1. Batch the requests up in a queue and send them x number at a time if it is possible
2. You could send an authorisation key with the request that only the server and central server could possibly know how to assemble. But that would leave your actual data in plain sight, which may or may not be a problem.
3. Not that I can immediately see

Comment: 1. Nearly all requests should be performed immediately (or something like that), so I'm afraid, queue is not an option.